# Unable to select my image element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image which is a size of 100x100px and I want to resize to 25%.

Despite giving the image it's own ID, then a class, then selecting it using it as a child, I am unable to change the size.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
  src: url(Roboto-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Medium";
  src: url(Roboto-Medium.ttf) format("truetype");
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
caption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 17%;
  /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidebarElement {
  margin: 6px 0px 13% 20%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #323232;
  display: block;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
}

.sidebarElement img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}

.selected {
  color: black;
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
}

.sidebarTitle {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #474747;
  display: block;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
}

.main {
  background-color: #c6ccd2;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 17%;
}

.content {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a class="sidebarTitle" href="localhost/">
    <h1>panel</h1>
  </a>

  <a class="sidebarElement selected" href="1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="home"> home
  </a>
  <a class="sidebarElement" href="2">tasks</a>
  <a class="sidebarElement" href="3">users</a>

  <a class="sidebarElement sidebarBottom" href="5">logout</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    d
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this code, my image should change size. However, it stays the same width and height. I am not sure if this is an issue with selecting, or if some inherited CSS property is preventing it from resizing.

Comment: 1. Make good use of Roboto web font provided by Google Fonts: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto; 2. Never use only one font in `font-family`; 3. Invalid `href` values in `<a>` tags; 4. Missing DOCTYPE and meta tags.

Comment: Also, you can make a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your code just works as expected :)

Comment: Consider closing the question!.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an element within my CSS stylesheet was overriding the properties I put on my image.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage is calculated from the parent, what percentage can we talk about if the parent does not have specific dimensions of height and width?

```css
.sidebarElement {
  margin: 6px 0px 13% 20%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #323232;
  display: block;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.sidebarElement img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<a class="sidebarElement selected" href="1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="home"> home
</a>
```